# Input type="text" to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, input, innerhtml

How do I type in 2 player names in `<input type="text">` and then by using JavaScript have them written out in `<th>` tags in a `<table>` using innerHTML for the `<th>`?

Here's a JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e94g3jm/)

Comment: Don't use same ID for input and td, id are unique

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6e94g3jm/5/

Comment: @Christoffer You want to have both player names in a single input box or different for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you have to use the `innerHTML`. Please take a look at following snippet.
Please note that you should give different id's to your html elements. An element's id should be unique.

```js
function saveNames(){

    // get the first's player name.
    var player1name = document.getElementById("player1name").value;
  
    // get the second's player name.
    var player2name = document.getElementById("player2name").value;
  
    // set the first's player name in the corresponding th.
    document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML = player1name;
  
    // set the second's player name in the corresponding th.
    document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML = player2name;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:10px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
}
td {
    text-align:center;
    width:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playerinputsection">
    <label for="player1name">Player 1</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="playernames" id="player1name">
</div>
<div class="playerinputsection">
    <label for="player2name">Player 2</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="playernames" id="player2name">
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="saveNames()">Save names</button>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="player1"></th>
        <th id="player2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For scenarios likes this, it would be more elegant to make use of an `MVVM` library, like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). However, using plain JavaScript you can have the same result. The mentioned library show it's power, when you have to build a more complex UI.